# OKD4.4 compute node failed with "Internal Server Error"

Tags: etcd, okd

I tried to deployed OKD 4.4 on my home cluster using the following doc =>
https://medium.com/@craig_robinson/openshift-4-4-okd-bare-metal-install-on-vmware-home-lab-6841ce2d37eb

The "services", "bootstrap" and "control-plane" nodes went smoothly (at least the output on screen is similar to those in the doc).

However, when I deployed the "compute" (worker) nodes, it failed to startup with the following error:

```
ignition[xxx]: GET https://api-int.lab.xxxtest.com:22623/config/worker: attempt #xxx
ignition[xxx]: GET result: Internal Server Error
```

A check on the bootstrap node (journalctl -u bootkube | grep bootkube.sh | tail):

```
[root@okd4-bootstrap openshift]# journalctl -u bootkube | grep bootkube.sh | tail
Apr 07 05:22:14 okd4-bootstrap.lab.xxxtest.com bootkube.sh[4838]: Error: unhealthy cluster
Apr 07 05:22:14 okd4-bootstrap.lab.xxxtest.com bootkube.sh[4838]: etcdctl failed. Retrying in 5 seconds...
Apr 07 05:22:24 okd4-bootstrap.lab.xxxtest.com bootkube.sh[4838]: {"level":"warn","ts":"2020-04-07T05:22:24.872Z","caller":"clientv3/retry_interceptor.go:61","msg":"retrying of unary invoker failed","target":"endpoint://client-57584517-34e6-40c3-b945-0b920fb059e6/localhost:2379","attempt":0,"error":"rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = latest connection error: connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial tcp [::1]:2379: connect: connection refused\""}
Apr 07 05:22:24 okd4-bootstrap.lab.xxxtest.com bootkube.sh[4838]: https://localhost:2379 is unhealthy: failed to commit proposal: context deadline exceeded
Apr 07 05:22:24 okd4-bootstrap.lab.xxxtest.com bootkube.sh[4838]: Error: unhealthy cluster
Apr 07 05:22:24 okd4-bootstrap.lab.xxxtest.com bootkube.sh[4838]: etcdctl failed. Retrying in 5 seconds...
Apr 07 05:22:35 okd4-bootstrap.lab.xxxtest.com bootkube.sh[4838]: {"level":"warn","ts":"2020-04-07T05:22:35.347Z","caller":"clientv3/retry_interceptor.go:61","msg":"retrying of unary invoker failed","target":"endpoint://client-304bfb54-2184-4c01-acdb-86850fbe9b8d/localhost:2379","attempt":0,"error":"rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = latest connection error: connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial tcp [::1]:2379: connect: connection refused\""}
Apr 07 05:22:35 okd4-bootstrap.lab.xxxtest.com bootkube.sh[4838]: https://localhost:2379 is unhealthy: failed to commit proposal: context deadline exceeded
Apr 07 05:22:35 okd4-bootstrap.lab.xxxtest.com bootkube.sh[4838]: Error: unhealthy cluster
Apr 07 05:22:35 okd4-bootstrap.lab.xxxtest.com bootkube.sh[4838]: etcdctl failed. Retrying in 5 seconds...
[root@okd4-bootstrap openshift]#
```

Any idea what could have gone wrong?
It seems bootstrap is trying to start/connect to "etcd" on the "localhost" (bootstrap node).

Thanks.

Comment: Hi All, I just figured this out. The problem was due to an expired certificate created during creation of manifest/ignition files. I recreated the manifest/ignition files using openshift-install command and all is well now!